# Samsung Galaxy suddenly installed many unremovable keyboards

Tags: samsung, keyboard, languages

Today, I looked at my Samsung Galaxy and found multiple "Keyboard downloaded" notifications. Afterward, I had many unwanted Keyboard languages instead of the previously configured Hebrew-English-Russian. I hadn't installed any apps or updates lately.

I went to Settings => General Management => Samsung Keyboard settings => Languages and types => Manage input languages and found many languages there.

[image: Manage input languages]

I could disable the unwanted languages, but when trying to delete I got "Can't delete preloaded languages".

Why did these languages become "preloaded" suddenly? They weren't before.

How can I remove them?

- Device: Samsung Galaxy A52, SM-A525F/DS, not purchased from a carrier
- OS: Android 13, One UI 5.1
- Samsung Keyboard version: latest - 5.6.10.31

Comment: If something is preloaded and can not be removed this is an indicator it is part of the system firmware. May be there was a firmware update installed before you recognized the download notifications?

Comment: As I wrote, I haven't installed any firmware update